# tikz define range of numbers (from x1 to x2)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
```

Is there a possibility to accomplish the same thing with something like the following pseudo-code:

```
\foreach \x in {x1 to x2}
```

Comment: `\foreach \x in {x1,...,x2}`. You can find more options in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @percusse says in the comment, various options for this are covered in the [`pgf` and `tikz` manual](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).  Here are a few examples:

- For the integers from 0 to 10:

  ```
  \foreach \x in {0,...,10}
  ```
- For the even integers from 0 to 10:

  ```
  \foreach \x in {0,2,...,10}
  ```

(The stepping is determined by the difference between the first two numbers provided.)

- You can change the pattern midway.  Thus, to get `0,1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12` write:

  ```
  \foreach \x in {0,...,4,6,8,...,12}
  ```

Comment: Inside a list you need 8 whitespaces for code marking ;)